# While i am trying to open my react app the CMD showing an npm err! Saying 'npm err! missing script:start' can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDfIC.jpg)

I've searched in previous answers and tried to solve this for many hours but with no success. I've typed in the terminal npm create-react-app, moved to the correct cd, and it gives me this error:

'npm ERR! missing script: start'

Comment: Can you paste package.json file?

Comment: I think when you do create-react-app , there is no need to do npm install , since node modules will already be there

Answer (score 1):

Start by validating that the 'start' script exists inside the package.json. That's where the script gets invoked. It should be under the key "scripts". If it's not there then that's the problem.

Should look something like this (if using react-scripts dependency):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ....
}
```

And if you're missing dependencies then run the following command inside the project directory to install them:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you have package.json in your project and it has the command **start** registered in it, example

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},